# Como chamar uma "Stored Procedure"?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Como chamar uma `procedure` em ASP.NET C#?

Segue a minha simples procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAdmin       
    (
    @email VARCHAR(50),
    @password VARCHAR (50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE Email = @email AND Password = @password
END
GO
```

Comment: Sugiro trocar o título, `procedure` é uma palavra bem genérica. Porém, não sei pelo que trocar.

Comment: @fotanus Como assim? Procedeure faz parte da sintaxe :S

Comment: O ideal seria Stored Procedure, comumente chamada de SP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeiramente você cria um Command em C#. O exemplo que segue é para SGBD SQL Server:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("GetAdmin");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "xxx@hgmail.com");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "abcd1234");

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Aí você utiliza a propriedade Connection do Command e passa um objeto do tipo SQLConnection, previamente configurado e que representa sua conexão ao Banco de Dados.

```
System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand("sp_AutalizaItemKDS");
```

Depois é só executar o Command:

```
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou de primeira!

Comment: Não entendi essa linha: `System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand("sp_AutalizaItemKDS");`, já que cmd está declarado acima. Poderiam me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 4):

Por acaso criei uma biblioteca apenas para chamar stored procedures da forma mais simples possível.

https://github.com/achvaicer/Neat.Procedure

É possível instalá-la através do NuGet.

`Install-Package Neat.Procedure`

```
ProcedureExecuter.ExecuteReader<SuaClasse>("GetAdmin");
```

Basta você ter uma classe onde as propriedades tem o mesmo nome das colunas retornadas, e o mapeamento é feito.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as informações acima.
Para executar uma stored procedure você pode fazer conforme o código abaixo:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   try
  {
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[nome_da_procedure]", conn);
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROC_PARAMETRO", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 100;
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROC_PARAMETRO1", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = 'valor';
      conn.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Alguns detalhes com relação a execução da procedure são: Você pode atribuir o resultado de uma procedure em uma variável:

```
var returnValue = command.ExecuteReader(); //Retorna a linha que foi executada
```

Pegando os valores retornados:

```
string variavel = "";
while (returnValue.Read())
{
    variavel = returnValue["COLUNA_TABELA"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver utilizando o Entity Framework, recomendo dar uma olhada nesses links aqui.

[EF with Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx)                     |            
[StackOverflow - EF with SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970416/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework)

Já com o EF6:

```
this.Database.SqlQuery("storedProcedureName",params);
```